# How to redeploy failed release?

Tags: git, maven, release, maven-release-plugin

I did first release using Maven release plugin. I had wrong settings in `distributionManagement` part in main `pom.xml` file, so the release failed. SCM plugin create a tag to GIT and updated versions in pom.xml.

I don't know what is the best practice for situations after failed release. I reverted version from release version to previous snapshot version in pom.xml, updated settings in distributionManagement part and ran the release again.

But it failed with result:

```
[ERROR] fatal: tag 'vc-0.0.6' already exists
```

How to fix it? Is it possible revert whole release from GIT, remove tag and run everything again?

Comment: The tag simply removed from git via `git tag -d vc-0.0.6` as well as remotely via `git push origin :vc-0.0.6` but more important is. Are artifacts already deplyoed? Have you access to that repository manager? If yes you could remove it but it depends.

Comment: Thanks, GIT commands was helpful. Now release ends with success, but in repository aren't all desirable files (war, jar). There is only main pom.xml file. My project has more submodules, but it is defined in main pom.xml file under profile part. I made a edit of the post.

Comment: Profiles are bad in relationship with modules. In other word never use [profiles in relationship with modules](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/).